# View is not rebuilding on controller call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

View:

```
@if (Model.IsEventActive)
{
    <div id="GameEvent">
        //SomeCode
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div id="GameNonEvent">
        //SomeCode
    </div>
}
```

JS file:

```
$('#btnNextEvent').click(function () {
     $.ajax({                
            type: "POST",
            url: "Game/UpdateUserEventInfo"
            //success: function () {
            //    $("#GameEvent").hide();
            //}
        });

});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUserEventInfo()
{
    var user = _user;
    _instance.Users.UpdateUserEventInfo(user);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!_instance.Users.CheckUserSkillsExist(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CreateChar");
    }

    _instance.GameBase.GetBaseData();
    var userModel = GetPlayerDisplayStats();
    return View(userModel);
}
```

If my beginning IsEventActive = true;

The FullEvent View at a certain moment calls my JS method which triggers the ajax call to UpdateUserEventInfo.

So, basically what is supposed to happen is when the Controller method UpdateUserEventInfo is fired, it updates the DB and then calls my index view again. Index view rebuilds the model and launches the view. 
The view checks for IsEventActive and builds the divs based on that.

The page shows the GameEvent Div in the beginning because IsEventActive is true, but when the index view rebuilds again via the ajax call. The if-else loops follows correctly and goes to the GameNonEvent div and creates it. But I do not see that on the page. The page still shows GamEvent Div. Even though the view didn't go into the if statement.

If i refresh the page, then it shows correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the part of the view that you showed in another container:

```
@if (Model.IsEventActive)
{
  <div id="container">
    <div id="GameEvent">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("FullEvent", "Game", new { ActiveEventGrpId = Model.ActiveEventGrpId }); }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Then, in `success` handler of `ajax` call do:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#container").html(data);
}
```

Comment: would not he end up with double declarations of all html elements this way  if his action returns complete page (data) ?

Comment: he has to make sure that in the case of `Model.IsEventActive == false` only html under `else` is returned.

Comment: This gives me an idea.
I can just create both divs on page load and make one of them hidden. 
Then on the success of the ajax call I can toggle the hidden classes.
That should work right?

Comment: yes, you can output all html in the Index view and hide/show parts of it when needed. Just don't redirect to Index from `UpdateUserEventInfo`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, is their anyway to set classes on a div based on razor model value?

Comment: something like: `<div style="display:@(Model.IsEventActive? "inline" : "none")">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

if i get your code right it looks like you are not doing anything with result of ajax call to "Game/UpdateUserEventInfo",
so nothing will happen. Where you have "success" commented out you should have code that updates view client side. Which could be a lot of code, it is possible that ajax call may not be even needed there, href to action will do just fine from functional point. The simple way
to fix this (since you say page refresh works) would be to put a page reload on ajax success :

```
 $.ajax({                
        type: "POST",
        url: "Game/UpdateUserEventInfo"
        success: function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
```

but this will also successfully cancel the whole point of using ajax, you may need review your approach for this.

Comment: But why should I have to use the success portion of the ajax call since my controller method calls redirects to the view? 
Sorry I am not very familiar with Ajax yet.

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials online, this should give you a good idea https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX  then you could better understand what success in jquery.ajax means under the hood so to speak